# How to create bigquery table log?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-logging

I want to see some logs when my bigquery dataset table added some data
added data, time, more

Then how to do that??

I find google logging But dont know how to create bigquery table log

Like bigquery table added rows

```
{'a':'123', 'b': '456', 'c': '789', 'd': '101112}
```

Then want to see logs data This

```
{'a':'123', 'b': '456', 'c': '789', 'd': '101112}
```

With Time or more

Comment: Did you try applying the resource filter in Cloud Logging? ie. `resource = BQ dataset`

Comment: try applying resouce filter but my bigquery table that connect GA 
So dont have logging 
I just want to make a log my bigquery table that connect GA

Comment: Could you edit your question and provide more information about your setup? How are your tables getting updated (through BQ console?)